# How to read this binary conversion to integer?

Tags: c#, binary, zip

I'm embarrassed to admits this but I have no idea how to read this. Please see the image. Though I know there is a million library's out there that would zip and unzip a file for me I want to learn and understand how to do this myself. So  my question is simple how do i convert the date in this image. under file modification time. it has `0x7d1c` how do they get `hour 15 minute 40 and second 56`. I'm hopelessly trying to understand but I don't understand how to convert. [image]

This is taken from [this](https://users.cs.jmu.edu/buchhofp/forensics/formats/pkzip-printable.html) site which is trying to explain the zip file format.

Sorry for the dumb question but I'm just at a lost.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time is stored with the hours in five bits, the minutes in six bits, and the seconds in five bits.

The value `0x7d1c` is `0111110100011100` in binary representation.

Splitting that up in the time components, you get `01111`, `101000` and `11100`.

The decimal represntation of `01111` is 15, `101000` is 40, and `11100` is 28.

The seconds are stored with half the resolution, i.e. the format can only represent every other second, so you multiply the seconds value by two.

So the time value is 15:40:56.

Comment: ahhhh!!!! I get it now. That's all I was looking to understand. Thanks for replying to this noob question. I was trying to figure this out for hours. yes im very embarrassed to admit. I would honor your answer as the answer in 5 minutes. Thank you!

Comment: Actually the number of hours is five bits, the number of minutes six and the number of seconds five again. If the number of seconds was stored in six bits, it would've had full resolution (2^6=64).

Comment: So why is your result different than what is in the image (14:40:56)?

Comment: @rmhartog: Yes, you are right, I got the bit count wrong. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [bitwise operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). From the picture it follows that the time field has sixteen bits with the following layout:

```
hhhhhmmmmmmsssss
0111110100011100 = 0x7d1c
```

Now, you want to *mask* out the bits that you are interested in. Let's say we want to get the number of hours first. We use the bitwise AND-operator (`&`) to mask out these bits. The AND-operator takes two operands. It will make each bit that is `1` in both operands also a `1`, and all others `0`.

```
hhhhhmmmmmmsssss
0111110100011100 = 0x7d1c
1111100000000000 = 0xf800
----------------
0111100000000000 = 0x7d1c & 0xf800 = 0x7800
```

Now you have only the bits of interest, the 'hour' bits. However, the zeroes to the right are not meaningful to us, so we use the right shift operator (`>>`) to move the bits into the right place, 11 places to the right.

```
0111100000000000 = 0x7d1c & 0xf800 = 0x7800
0000000000001111 = (0x7d1c & 0xf800) >> 11 = 0xF = 15
```

This is your result; 15 hours. The general rule in this case is this:

```
hours = (value & 0xf800) >> 11;
minutes = (value & 0x7e0) >> 5;
seconds = (value & 0x1f) * 2; // the number of seconds is rounded to an even number
                              // to save a bit, so multiply by two (see picture).
```

I'll leave it to you to verify the last two lines. Note that the windows calculator on 'programmer mode' is an invaluable tool for binary / hex / decimal conversions.